# How to properly combine template Repository class and CRTP pattern to provide both type polymorphism and eliminate virtual call cost?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, crtp

This is a repository class, which has such interface. As you can see, the key type and value type are both template parameters. I add an extra `Impl` parameter, since i want to use the CRTP pattern to eliminate virtual call cost.

```cpp
template <typename K, typename V, typename Impl>
class Repository{
public:
    V get(const K& key){
        return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->get(key);
    }
};
```

And the dummy implementation class goes here:

```cpp
struct MockData{
    char data[16384];
};

class RepositoryImpl : public Repository<int, MockData, RepositoryImpl>{
public:
    MockData get(const int& key){
        std::cout << "haha";
        return MockData{};
    }
};
```

The caller has such signature:

```cpp
template<typename Impl>
MockData doSomething(Repository<int, MockData, Impl>* obj){
    return obj->get(1);
}
```

And there might be more than one `RepositoryImpl` that has the same `K V` interface. For example, a `SQLiteBasedRepo` or a `LMDBBasedRepo`...

---

The above code can compile, but what i want to ask is, is it the proper way to combine template Repository class and CRTP pattern to provide both type polymorphism and eliminate virtual call cost? The current implementation mix the CRTP implementation detail(the `Impl` template parameter) and the functional parameter(`K` and `V`) together, which is a little bit strange to me.

Comment: Since you want no indirect calls, your client has to know the real type (here, as a template argument to `doSomething`).  What are you hoping to accomplish with the `Repository` class template that you can’t do with just an `Impl*` parameter?

Comment: @DavisHerring There might be some other impl class that shared the same ```K V``` interface, for example, a ```SqliteBasedRepo``` or a ```LMDBBasedRepo```...

Comment: `template<typename Impl> MockData doSomething(Repository<int, MockData, Impl>* obj)` is functionally equivalent to `template<typename Impl>
MockData doSomething(Impl* obj)`; your code should work unchanged if you make this substitution. It's unclear what role `Repository` is supposed to play.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i personally prefer a explicit interface class than implicit function signature dependency if possible.

Comment: You might be able to extract `K` and `V` from `Impl`, rather than passing them explicitly. In the simplest case, you could require `Impl` to provide typedefs with certain names. If you want to be fancier, you could detect the signature of `Impl::get` method (as long as there are no overloads).